How to make the result obtained by vtkSelectPolyData have smooth edges in VTK
I need to set a certain area in PolyData to a different color.
The edge of this area is smooth, but directly changing the original PolyData will get jagged edges due to the triangles.
I don't mind modifying the data of the original PolyData. How can I get a smooth edge first and then set the color like using vtkClipPolyData?
I don't want to cut the model, so I can't use vtkClipPolyData directly
